# Is "the establishment" a formal word for "store"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

I have looked up in three different dictionaries, but I didn't find anything that mentions establishment can also mean "a store". Now, I'm questioning myself whether I have understood the meaning of store itself.

I knew this word from a language learning app. It's originally the translation of the word "el establecimiento" in Spanish as you can see on this screenshot here:

[image]

I believe, before knowing this information I would think "establishment" is something like the act of establishing. My second guess orginally was that it's possibly a literal translation, but in the dictionary it also means the same sense as in English. Is there something obvious I didn't notice here?

Comment: Collins Dictionary mentions a shop, which is what a 'store' is.

Comment: Even though the meaning is correct (though maybe unusual in this context), I don't think the given example is in any way something any native speaker would ever say.

Comment: Seems equivalent to '*bricks and mortar*' signifying actual, physical premises, as opposed to internet or online shopping

Comment: @MichaelHarvey But isn't it simply that "establishment" is a general term which can stand for anything - including a restaurant, or a place of entertainment. I have certainly seen notices - perhaps rather dated now -  which say things like "The establishment cannot be responsible for personal property left on the premises". Ah - I've just noticed that you've answered to that very effect!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An 'establishment' can be any type of business where people can enter a building or place, not just a store.

> Establishment
>
> 2. COUNTABLE NOUN
>
> An establishment is a shop, business, or organization occupying a
> particular building or place.
>
> [formal]
>
> ...a scientific research establishment.
>
> ...shops and other commercial establishments.

[Establishment (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/establishment)